# Insert a character when capturing group

Tags: regex

I want to select a group out of a given string and insert a character in position 5 of that group.

Input String:   `xxx123456789yyy`

Expression:  `^x{3}(?<serialno>\d{5}\d{4})y{3}$`

Output (serialno): `123456789`

Now I want the serialno group to contain a 'A' between 5 and 6, so that I get '12345A6789' instead of 123456789'. The character is always an 'A' and I want to do this in one Regular Expression.
Is it possible to do this with match or do I have to call match and replace?

Comment: regularexpression is to match the input string. We could capture the charcters into groups. But it isn't possible to add some charters to to the captured group. If you do like that then it won't match the input string.

Comment: Match matches, replace changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't alter a string with a match, so you'll need to use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$output = preg_replace('/^x{3}(\d{5})(\d{4})y{3}$/', '$1A$2', $input);
```

Comment: It seems that I have to do this in two steps